# Where did the term "chicken walker" come from?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, history-of, names

Before I knew the actual names for Scout Walkers or AT-STs, I simply knew them as "chicken walkers", as have many other *Star Wars* fans. However, I don't know where that term came from, I don't *think* the films or any official *Star Wars* media ever called it that, but I could be wrong. How did fans come to refer to AT-STs as "chicken walkers"? Where did that term come from?

[image]

Comment: Because it looks like a chicken walking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_walker

Comment: @Richard To be honest, I've never really seen the resemblance. Chickens don't have legs that reach their heads and their legs are under them, as opposed to connected to the sides like the AT-ST's.

Comment: [Wookieepedia says the term first appeared in-universe in the recent *Star Wars Battlefront*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Scout_Transport#Appearances), but the term is definitely older than that.

Comment: @CBredlow Great find, terribly-written page.

Comment: @RogueJedi It is, I'm trying to find a better source for the origin of the term and how it relates to the AT-ST, but all I see is how GL thought the design was 'neat' and included it in ESB :/

Comment: They're chickens and AT-ATs are cows. To everyone ever!

Comment: @ThruGog AT-ATs are camels, everyone knows that.

Comment: @CBredlow - People have gone to war over less ;-)

Comment: @ThruGog [AT-ATs are dogs.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CVYOCMpJRY)

Comment: @RogueJedi For all we know, Star Wars chickens might look *exactly* like AT-STs.

Comment: @CBredlow "all I see is how GL thought the design was 'neat' and included it in ESB" see my new question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126103/why-is-there-a-glimpse-of-an-at-st-in-the-empire-strikes-back

Comment: @ThruGog What? AT-ATs are trunkless elephants!

Comment: @Rogue Jedi - That's a beautiful and funny video. But get real. Cows! Janus Bahs Jacquet - Cows!

Comment: @RedCaio I saw, and posted an answer there too.

Comment: Ironically I always called them AT-STs and didn't know people actually called them "chicken walkers".

Answer (score 14):

Out of universe: The phrase 'chicken walkers' refer to the type of articulation in the legs.  This term applies to all mechs with this type of articulation. Other mechs with this type of articulation: ED-209, AT-PT(features in the games), and the AT-RT (featured in RotS, and Clone Wars)  This type of motion is often faster than a more 'man-type' motion, but supposedly can't handle rugged terrain as well. (Which I don't know if I agree with that idea, as we see it used almost exclusively in rugged terrain, but we do see an AT-ST slip on logs during the battle of endor)

In universe: There really is no reference to calling these things in the novels or movies.

Source: [Wikipedia-Chicken Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_walker)

Comment: To add upon this answer, in Star Wars: Rogue Squadron for the N64 there is a cheat code called 'CHICKEN' that lets you play a secret level as an AT-ST

Comment: @TaylorAllred wasn't that the level that took place on the surface of the death star?

Comment: No, it took place on Tatooine, it was a very small circular map, all you could do was really walk around and shoot houses I'm pretty sure. I think it was like a left over tech demo that they decided to make a secret level, or at least, that's what it felt like.

Answer (score 3):

Its legs bend in the same way a chicken's legs bend, and so when it walks, it looks like a chicken. It is worth noting that the AT-ST is not the only "chicken-walker", it is a more general term used across a variety of sci-fi stories to describe many different types of mech / robots with similar legs. The ED-209 in Robocop was also called a chicken walker, as was the X-1 Alpha in Future cop and many others. It is not a term specific to Star Wars.

Answer (score -2):

*Star Wars Battlefront II* (old) had rebels that would call out "Chicken Walker!"

Comment: Do you have a source for this?